# Kubernetes ingress websockets connection issue

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, nginx-ingress, aws-elb

Deployed k8s on AWS with KOPS.
I have created nginx ingress https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
nginx-ingress-controller image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.18.0

Everything is up and running and I could able to access applications externally using aws classic load balancer which is created by nginx service.

Recently we started working on websockets. I deployed my services in k8s and trying to access externally.

I created service and ingress for my application. Ingress is now pointing to loadbalancer(below json file).

I created route53 entry in aws and trying to connect to that but I am getting below error when I am trying to connect from my client application through chrome browser

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://blockchain.aro/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

I tried creating Application load balancer but I could not able to connect to `wss://<host>`

Error:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://blockchain.aro/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'wss://blockchain.aro',
  options: { autoConnect: false, transports: ['websocket']} };


Ingress:

   "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"extensions/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"Ingress\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"blockchain\",\"namespace\":\"adapt\"},\"spec\":{\"rules\":[{\"host\":\"blockchain.aro\",\"http\":{\"paths\":[{\"backend\":{\"serviceName\":\"blockchain\",\"servicePort\":8097},\"path\":\"/\"},{\"backend\":{\"serviceName\":\"blockchain\",\"servicePort\":8097},\"path\":\"/socket.io\"},{\"backend\":{\"serviceName\":\"blockchain\",\"servicePort\":8097},\"path\":\"/ws/\"}]}}],\"tls\":[{\"hosts\":[\"blockchain.aro\"],\"secretName\":\"blockchain-tls-secret\"}]}}\n",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout": "3600",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout": "3600"
    }
```

included `tls` and `secretname` and `rules` in ingress file. I tried creating `ApplicationLoadbalancer` but I could not able to connect with that too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: core-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: core-service
    nginx.org/websocket-services: core-service
  name: core-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: core-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.io
    secretName: core-prod
```

Comment: I updated asp per your inputs.  gettting handshake error as .  WebSocket connection to 'wss://blockchain.aro/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

Comment: @Ram try adding anotation if you are on AWS `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
`

Comment: Or you can also do it like : "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"

"

Comment: @Ram worked? Please update the status of question if it's helped you can upvote and if worked mark it as answer. This is how it's work

Comment: Sure Harsha, I updated and looks like it is connecting, but I could see that websockets information in pod logs like "websocket connection received from client" in server, but getting same error in client "failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.. I am checking if this is code issue. I will check and update. Again appreciate your support, I will revert to this and update without fail.

Comment: Thank you, googled for 30 minutes before finding this

Comment: Specifically, for deploying an R Shiny app I had to set the nginx websocket-services annotations

Comment: I found this article that explains why it happens and an alternate solution, [here](https://medium.com/johnjjung/how-to-use-gcp-loadbalancer-with-websockets-on-kubernetes-using-services-ingresses-and-backend-16a5565e4702)