# Web Socket wss:// in AWS EKS with nginx Ingress. returns 400. ws://, http:// and https:// works perfectly

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've been trying to run few services in AWS EKS Cluster. I followed the ingress-nginx guide to get https with AWS ACM certificate

> https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws

Used tls termination at ingress controller

I used 3 routes for each services as

**adminer.xxxx.com** - points to an adminer service

**socket.xxxx.com** - points to the wss service written in nodejs

**service.xxxx.com** - points to a program that returns a page which connects to socket url

Without TLS Termination, in http:// everything works fine, **ws://socket.xxxx.com/socket.io** gets connected and responds well.

When I add TLS, the request goes to **wss://socket.xxxx.com/socket.io** and the nginx returns 400. I Can't figure out why it happens.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    # nginx.ingress.kuberenetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: adminer.xxxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: adminer-svc
              servicePort: 8080
    - host: socket.xxxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nodejs-svc
              servicePort: 2020
    - host: service.xxxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: django-svc
              servicePort: 8000
```

I Tried with and without these configurations

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Also I've tried changing the **socket.xxxx.com** into **service.xxxx.com** and assigned to be forwarded for ***/socket.io*** path

I've also put a url in nodejs with express to test if its working at all, and it responds properly in https://

Only the wss:// has the issue.

PS : This entire Service works when nginx is setup in a normal system  with nginx configuration

```
location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:2020/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I tried request like this as well

https://node-socket.xxxx.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling this works

https://node-socket.xxxx.comsocket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket this doesnt.

Combinations I tried

```
protocol, balancer, backendproto, transport => result
wss://, ELB, TCP, websocket  =>  400
wss://, NLB, TCP, websocket  =>  400
wss://, ELB, HTTP, websocket  =>  400
wss://, NLB, HTTP, websocket  =>  400
ws://, ELB, TCP, websocket => 400
ws://, ELB, HTTP, websocket => 400
ws://, NLB, TCP, websocket => 400
ws://, NLB, HTTP, websocket => 400
```

polling worked in every cases

Comment: check the logs of nginx ingress controller to check possible causes of 400 response code.

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534215/kubernetes-ingress-websockets-connection-issue

Comment: I found out the 400 is from nginx controller while checking the logs. There is no further explainations. Just bad request. checked via kubectl logs, should I check anywhere else            ?

Comment: I don't have the certificate files to add like that, I'm using aws ACM i just have an ARN to add.

Comment: I think there is related[ github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3746) about that, take a look. To be more precisely check this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3746#issuecomment-474507823). So it should work if you terminate ssl on nginx side.

Comment: I've already tried that @jt97 but my other services running in http not working when i changed that -backend-protocol: "tcp"

Comment: Did you try making two different Ingress resource , one with `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"` for your current issue and one without this for other routes ?

Comment: @TarunKhosla absolutely , I tried 

1) wss:// tcp elb websocket 
2) wss:// tcp nlb websocket
3) wss:// http elb websocket
4) wss:// http nlb websocket

nothing worked, but polling works

Comment: So far did you manage to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be missing

```
nginx.org/websocket-services
```

annotation

It's value should be a value of kubernetes service name.
See https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

@pitor, both ingresses are different, so annotations will differ.

Comment: This can be just a comment below the question