# Socket.io Ingress controller on Kubernetes (Can't estabilish a connection)

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, socket.io, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a simple Node.js chat example which uses socket.io. I have tested this deployment with a docker container locally, and a web client succesfully connects to the websocket (socket.io). The problem arise when I try to deploy this on a Kubernetes cluster with an ingress Controller.

My question is, is there anything ***special*** socket.io specifically needs when using an ingress controller?

**The error message I get is** `<<browser name>> Can't estabilish a connection to the server at ws://<<address>>/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=websocket`

Below is the simple implementation of the **server side**

```
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    console.log('made socket connection')
    socket.on('chat', (message)=>{
        message:message.value
    })
```

Below is the client:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3002", {
    upgrade: false,
    transports: ['websocket'],
    secure: True
});
```

My **ingress** yaml file looks like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ws-ingress
  namespace: websocket-ns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "ws-service"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      http {
        server {
            listen 3002;
          location = / {
              proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
              proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
          upstream nodes {
              hash $remote_addr consistent;
              server app01:3002;
            }
      }
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "$host_address"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ws-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ws-service
  namespace: websocket-ns
  labels:
    app: ws-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ws-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3002
```

Server deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws-app
  namespace: websocket-ns
  labels:
    app: ws-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ws-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ws-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ws-app
          image: themuchy/socketexample
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3002
              name: ws-app
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58534529/5525824

Comment: not sure why you have added the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` and upgrading the HTTP to websocket in config. That nginx controller will do it by own

Comment: in ingress you traffic going into the `ws-service` however in annotation you mentioned another service name.

Comment: @HarshManvar I used the same service name (ws-service) for ingress and in annotation, sorry, I just forgot to change the name in the annotation before I posted the question here (had been trying out a different solution).

Answer (score 1):

This one is working with one

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: core-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: ws-service
    nginx.org/websocket-services: ws-service
  name: core-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ws-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.io
    secretName: core-prod
```

Nginx itself will upgrade the HTTP request and convert it to WebSocket. You don't have to add any annotation of the same.

`Deployment` and `service`, `YAML` configuration looking good however try removing the annotation `server-snippet`. This way traffic flow will be something like

```
LB > ingress (Connection upgrade) > service > pods
```

Comment: Thank you, but this still couldn't work for me. Could it be because I'm using https instead of SSL?

Comment: for https there is already i have added the block which will terminate the https at ingress level maybe you check on that once

Answer (score 1):

been banging my head against the wall for a whole day!
to find out that one line in the annotations solves the problem!
i figured it out by reducing the replicas to 1, then it worked, very quickly became evident that the whole issue was SESSION STICKINESS!
[see socket io multiple nodes](https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/)

the mighty line is: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "$client_ip"

here's my Ingress rule

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nodejs-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    ##### solved ws socket.io session stickness #####
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "$client_ip"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    - www.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: nodejs
            port:
              number: 5000
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: nodejs
            port:
              number: 5000
```